# How to speed up range joins in bigquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, query-optimization

Doing self join with same table with range condition. The below is sql statement.

```
select 
current_rec .*
,compare_rec.employee_id as less_salary_employee
from 
hr.employees current_rec
left join hr.employees compare_rec 
on current_rec.hire_date  < compare_rec .hire_date and current_rec.salary < compare_rec.salary 
order by current_rec .employee_id ;
```

for 300K records, it is taking more 45~60 min. After googling, i came to know that Binned range join optimization will help. i read this article to improve query performance.
[https://select.dev/posts/snowflake-range-join-optimization#how-to-optimize-range-joins-in-snowflake][1] . But not able to understanding. can someone explain it? . Specially binned range optimization part . if you provide visual representation that will help

Comment: I would suggest to try to solve the questions with self joined tables. Can you answer your tasks without the full joined table? I would guess, that you need several KPI for each employee_id, such as how many other employee_id are hired later and earn more. What have the other emploryees as average, maximum sallery.

Comment: Please update your question with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve - include sample data and the result you want based on that data (all as editable text)

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the actual DBMS you are using. You’ve tagged it with both PostgreSQL and BQ and then linked to an article about Snowflake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a CTE to bin the employees table into ranges based on hire date
Join the CTE against itself, filtering on current_rec.bin >= compare_rec.bin to only join relevant bins
Add the additional filter on salary to complete the range join logic
This allows joining in a more optimized way by avoiding comparing rows across irrelevant bins.

```
WITH bins AS (
  SELECT *,
    CASE 
      WHEN hire_date < '2010-01-01' THEN 1
      WHEN hire_date >= '2010-01-01' AND hire_date < '2015-01-01' THEN 2
      WHEN hire_date >= '2015-01-01' AND hire_date < '2020-01-01' THEN 3
      WHEN hire_date >= '2020-01-01' THEN 4
    END AS bin
  FROM hr.employees
)

SELECT 
  current_rec.*, 
  compare_rec.employee_id AS less_salary_employee
FROM bins current_rec
LEFT JOIN bins compare_rec
  ON  current_rec.bin >= compare_rec.bin
  AND current_rec.salary < compare_rec.salary
ORDER BY current_rec.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

A table with 300K records which is self joinded, results in 90 billion operations. I am astonished that it only took one hour to performe this amount.

First we do a estimation by grouping the data, then we use this result to obtain the exact solution.

To optimize this task it might be helpful to group the table by category. Do you really need to compare the exact date of hiring and the exact salary? I would suggest truncating the hiring day to the month and rounding the salary to $1000. This resulted in my case to 12K records. This still results in over 100K operations, but this query runs in a minute.

```sql
#create table Test.worker2 as
With tbl as
(
SELECT
  round(salary/1000)*1000 salary, 
  date_trunc(hire_date,month) as hire_month,
  COUNT(1) as counts,
  array_agg(id) id
FROM
  Test.worker
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
)

Select * except(B),
B.*
from(
Select A.* ,
((Select struct(count(1) as LessSalaray_id_counts,ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(B.id) as LessSalaray_id) from tbl B where A.hire_month<B.hire_month and A.salary<B.salary
)) as B
from tbl A
)
```

For obtaining the exact calculation, please remove the `#` in the fist line and replace both the `<` by `<=` to export the data in a new table of several gb size. Then run this query

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Test.worker3 AS
SELECT a.*,B_id
FROM Test.worker2,
  UNNEST(id) AS A_id,
  UNNEST(lesssalaray_id) B_id
LEFT JOIN Test.worker a
ON A_id=a.id
LEFT JOIN Test.worker b
ON  B_id=b.id
WHERE 
  a.hire_date<b.hire_date
  AND a.salary<b.salary
```

which will run quite long, but after about 20 minutes, you obtain the extact answer.

Comment: On top of that, you can also do further optimizations such as partitioning and clustering. 

Partition it on the "hire_date" column. This can help to prune unnecessary partitions during query execution. Additionally, clustering the table on the "salary" column might improve the efficiency of the self-join, especially if you're often performing range comparisons on that column.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this with PostgreSQL, so I'm giving a PostgreSQL answer.  I don't know if it also works in bigquery or snowflake or whatever other PostgreSQL derivative/knockoff you might care to mention.  You just create a GiST index, then run the query you already have shown, and it does all the rest of the work for you.

```
create extension btree_gist ;
create index on employees using gist (hire_date,salary);
```